# Would the FAA let me fly a plane with no windows?

Tags: faa, regulations, airbus, hypotheticals

Back in 2014 [Airbus patented several designs for airplanes with no cockpit windows](https://www.seattlepi.com/business/boeing/article/Airbus-Pilots-don-t-really-need-windows-5596374.php#photo-6548296).

Would the FAA let someone (fully-certified for IFR) fly an airplane with no cockpit windows?

Comment: Are you certified for IVR?

Comment: Good point!  I've clarified my question.

Comment: Do you mean to replace the out the window view with cameras or to have no OTW view at all- just instruments including or not including synthetic vision?

Comment: Yes, drone pilots do that all the time.

Answer (score 7):

If such an aircraft were to obtain a type certificate, and if you subsequently obtained a type rating in that aircraft, then the answer is yes.

Both aircraft and you would have had the proper testing and certification necessary to operate together and the FAA would let you fly that airplane.

Otherwise the answer is no.